# making a link accessible only from specific webpage same domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a simple way to make a webpage only accessible from a specified link?

I have a webpage with [prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) popups. The popup is calling an html page with a jwplayer script. I'd like to avoid anyone going directly to that page being called into prettyphoto.

**EDIT** : (code from comments)

```
<ul class="gallery clearfix">
    <p class="p-bigger">more about sftc</p>
    <li><a href="vids/sc1.html?iframe=true&width=650&height=650" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="more about sftc"><img src="images/scene-images/sc1.jpg" width="180" height="135" /></a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to have this link only be available from this page, and not for someone to copy this link, paste it in a browser and go directly to that page being called

Comment: what exactly do you mean with `from a specified link`? from an specific page? or from a specific link structure like `http://domain.com/page.html#prettyPhoto`? show the html that calls that page in any case

Comment: There's no real way to check in PHP (that I know of)... But you could check `window.top` in javascript.

Comment: I want to be able to have this link only be available from this page, and not for someone to copy this link, paste it in a browser and go directly to that page being called

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned, the link can be spoofed but since that page should be opened inside an iframe (prettyphoto iframe mode) then at least you can check if it was opened inside an iframe.

You can add this to the `sc1.html` page :

```
var is_iframe = self != top;

if( !is_iframe ){
    // page is not inside an iframe so redirect 
    window.location.href = "http://www.mypage.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short: Nope not really possible.  You could check the referring link, but that can easily be spoofed.